# Scala Play form validation: different forms for one case class - is it possible?

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, mapping, playframework-2.0

I'm looking for a way to use two different forms for one case class. I was trying to do that with additional constructor, but failed with that. Look at the code snippet:

```
case class LoginDetails(password: String, field3: Option[Int], field4: String)

case class User(username: String, loginDetails: LoginDetails) {
   def this(username: String, password: String, field3: Option[Int], field4: String) = this(username, LoginDetails(password, field3, field4))
// some logic inside
    }

val loginDetailsForm = Form(
 mapping(
   "password" -> text,
   "field3" -> optional(number),
   "field4" -> text
 )(LoginDetails.apply)(LoginDetails.unapply))

val oldForm = Form(
 mapping(
   "username" -> email,
   "password" -> text,
   "field3" -> optional(number),
   "field4" -> text
 )(User.apply)(User.unapply))

val newForm = Form(
     mapping(
       "username" -> email,
       "loginDetails" -> loginDetailsForm.mapping
     )(User.apply)(User.unapply))
```

What I'm trying to do is to support two API's (new and old one), but if I will have two copies of the same case class, I will have to make code logic duplicates in many many places in the rest of the code. If there is a way to do that?

Of course given code doesn't work and is used like an example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to add methods `applyOld` and `unapplyOld` to companion object like this:

```
case class User(username: String, loginDetails: LoginDetails)
object User {
  def applyOld(username: String, password: String, field3: Option[Int], field4: String) = new User(username, LoginDetails(password, field3, field4))
  def unapplyOld(u: User): Option[(String, String, Option[Int], String)] =
    Some((u.username, u.loginDetails.password,  u.loginDetails.field3,  u.loginDetails.field4))
}
```

You just need methods `(String, String, Option[Int], String) => User` and `User => Option[(String, String, Option[Int], String)]`, you could place them anywhere you like. For instance you could create object `UserOld` with methods `apply` and `unapply`.

Usage:

```
val oldForm = Form(
 mapping(
   "username" -> email,
   "password" -> text,
   "field3" -> optional(number),
   "field4" -> text
 )(User.applyOld)(User.unapplyOld))

val newForm = Form(
     mapping(
       "username" -> email,
       "loginDetails" -> loginDetailsForm.mapping
     )(User.apply)(User.unapply))
```

Comment: Got the idea, thanks. I was hoping it will be possible to do without making  companion object. As I have ~100 classes, which will be supporting both API's, I couldn't avoid verbosity. 
I will wait a bit, may be there will be some other answer with more elegant way, but I doubt. Then I will mark your answer like a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @britva: you have to create this 2 functions somehow. It's not necessary to place them in companion object. You could even create them "in place": mapping(...)((a, b, c, d) => ...)(user => Some((...))).

Answer (score 3):

You can do the apply/unapply directly where the form is defined instead. Then you don't have to add any new constructors to the case class.

```
val oldForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "username" -> email,
    "password" -> text,
    "field3" -> optional(number),
    "field4" -> text
  )(
    (username, password, field3, field4) =>
      User(username, LoginDetails(password, field3, field4))
  )(
    (user: User) =>
      Option(user.username, user.loginDetails.password, user.loginDetails.field3, user.loginDetails.field4)
  )
)

val newForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "username" -> email,
    "loginDetails" -> loginDetailsForm.mapping
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply))
```