# How to init case class from one JSON string instead of separate fields of form

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

New to the Play framework.

After reading the [doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms), I know the standard way to initialize case class by using form like this:

```
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.format.Formats._

val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> of[String],
    "age" -> of[Int],
    "email" -> of[String]
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)
```

in this case, we provide separate textboxes for user to fill in in the web interface, after submit, the server code will init User according to the form. Works Great!

but, what if what I wanna provide is only one textbox, and user(actually the mobile guy who wanna test the web service API) should fill in a complete JSON string and then post it to server to create a User instance?

Would appreciate if you can provide both the view & controller code.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want your **user** to write JSON? (This seems like a fairly strange use-case.)

Comment: @Mikesname actually, I want to develope a simple web interface for the android developer test our web service API

Answer (score 0):

Taking your question literally (creating an object via JSON from a *form field*), it could look something like below. For completeness I've also provided the direct (and much simpler) way to unmarshall an object from JSON in a controller action (using content type `application/json` instead of `application/x-form-urlencoded`).

To extract a custom type (in your case a `User` object) from a form field you need to write a mapper to bind/unbind the data to/from a string. The `userJsonMapper` in the `User`'s companion object does this, giving an error (`error.jsonObj`, for which you can provide an i18n translation) if JSON parsing fails.

The model code `app/models/User.scala`:

```
package models     

case class User(name: String, age: Int, email: String)

object User {
  // Create a generic JSON format using the macro. NB: This
  // does *NOT* include validation of the email or age fields.
  import play.api.libs.json.{Format, Json}
  implicit val format: Format[User] = Json.format[User]

  // Create a form and a field binder that validates the contents
  // of the "json" field to ensure it is valid JSON for a user.
  import play.api.data.Form
  import play.api.data.Forms._
  import play.api.data.FormError
  import play.api.data.format.Formatter

  // The actual form object
  val jsonForm: Form[User] = Form(
    single("json" -> of(userJsonMapper))
  )

  // Map a User object to/from a form field
  def userJsonMapper: Formatter[User] = new Formatter[User] {
    def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]) = {
      play.api.data.format.Formats.stringFormat.bind(key, data).right.flatMap { s =>
        scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch[User]
          .either(Json.parse(s).as[User])
          .left.map(e => Seq(FormError(key, "error.jsonObj", Nil)))
      }
    }
    def unbind(key: String, value: User) = Map(key -> Json.stringify(Json.toJson(value)))
  }
}
```

The template code `app/views/createUserForm.scala.html`:

```
@(form: Form[User], action: Call)(implicit request: RequestHeader)

<html>
    <body>
        @helper.form(action = action, 'role -> "form") {
            @helper.inputText(form("json"))
            <button type="submit">Create User</button>
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

The route file `conf/routes`:

```
GET         /createUser                     controllers.Users.createUser
POST        /createUser                     controllers.Users.createUserPost

# For good measure, include an action to create
# a user directly from JSON via a JSON content-type.
POST        /createUserJson                 controllers.Users.createUserPostJson
```

The controller code `app/controllers/Users.scala`:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import models.User

object Users extends Controller {

  def createUser = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.createUserForm(
      User.jsonForm,
      controllers.routes.Users.createUserPost()
    ))
  }

  def createUserPost = Action { implicit request =>
    User.jsonForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      // Form data is bad - re-render form.
      errForm => BadRequest(views.html.createUserForm(
        errForm,
        controllers.routes.Users.createUserPost()
      )),
      user =>
        // Create user here
        Ok(s"User: $user")
    )
  }
}

// A more direct way of doing this is to POST the data
// as application/json and unmarshall it directly.
def createUserPostJson = Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>
  request.body.validate[User].fold(
    errs => BadRequest(play.api.libs.json.JsError.toFlatJson(errs)),
    user => Ok(s"User: $user")
  )
}
```

Comment: really appreciate your answer. a little lost when I try to understand the `bind` method of `userJsonMapper`, maybe there are too many new content for a beginner like me. Are there any document about Formatter I can refer to? btw, I have find another way to do the thing I want, plz check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24603818/404145

Comment: Is it possible to write object User in a generic way, so it would be possible to do something like object User extends BaseSchema[User] ?

Answer (score 0):

After reading this thread: [Scala Play form validation: different forms for one case class - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896688/scala-play-form-validation-different-forms-for-one-case-class-is-it-possible?rq=1), figured out a way to do what I want.

The canonical way of extracting fields from form to create an instance is like this:

```
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.format.Formats._

val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> of[String],
    "des" -> of[String],
    ...
  )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)
```

here we create a form and then bind the target object's apply and unapply methods to it, thanks to these methods, the form now has the ability to extract fields and turn them into Object.

What I wanna do is a form which can turn a JSON string(instead of separate fields) into an object, then why not provide the form with functions like this:

```
json:String => User
```

yes, additional to User's apply&unapply function, we add:

```
  def applyStr(jsonStr: String): User = {
    val json: JsValue = Json.parse(jsonStr)

    val validateResult: JsResult[User] = json.validate[User](UserReads)
    validateResult match{
      case s: JsSuccess[User] => s.get
      case e: JsError => null
    }
  }

  def unapplyToStr(user: User): Option[String] = {
    Some(Json.toJson(user).toString())
  }
```

and create a form like this:

```
  val userJSONForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "json" -> text
    )(User.applyStr)(User.unapplyToStr)
  )
```

now we have a form which can turn json string into User, what left is familiar, we create an action in controller to display form:

```
  def createByJson() = Action {
    Ok(views.html.user_json(userJSONForm))
  }
```

the corresponding view is like:

```
@(userJsonForm: Form[User])

@helper.form(action = routes.UserController.saveJson()) {
    @helper.textarea(userJsonForm("json"))

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

after submit, the form will be delivered to UserController.saveJson():

```
  def saveJson() = Action{implicit request =>
    userJSONForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => {
        BadRequest(views.html.user_json(formWithErrors))
      },
      user => {
        //do sth to the user
        ...

        Ok("get user")
      }
    )
  }
```